# How to return only selected columns from querybuilder in guidewire v10?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I want to return only two columns from the entity-Check. I tried below but it doesnt work. Please note that I am using Guidewire version 10.

Query.make(entity.Check)
.compare(Check#Createtime, Equals, time)
.select({QuerySelectColumns.pathWithAlias("CheckNumber", Paths.make(Check#CheckNumber)),
QuerySelectColumns.pathWithAlias("InvoiceNumber", Paths.make(Check#InvoiceNumber)) })?.FirstResult

Answer (score 1):

what do u mean saying it doesnot work? what doe sit return to u?

> var query = Query.make(Check)
> .compare(ReasonCodeParametersRgs#ProductCode, Equals, "smth")
> .select({
> QuerySelectColumns.pathWithAlias("CheckNumber", Paths.make(Check#Field1)),
> QuerySelectColumns.pathWithAlias("InvoiceNumber", Paths.make(Check#Field2))
> })

> var count: Integer = query?.FirstResult?.ColumnCount
> print("!!!count = " + count)

this code returns 2 if query got any rows and 0 if query is empty. I've checked it with different entity and conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can use below snippet.

var conQuery = Query.make(Person).select(\row -> new String[]{row.FirstName, row.LastName})
print(conQuery.first()) //just prints first row

Here the return type of conQuery will be IQueryBeanResult<String[]>.
Each returned row will contain array of String with FirstName and LastName.

If only FirstName needed, use => select(\row -> row.FirstName)